# using ms office com objects in other systems without have office installed

Tags: c#, dll, office-2007

i wrote a app for reading excel files.i had to add some references to Microsoft office Com Objects.
it worked good in my system,but when i wanted to use it in other system in which does`t had ms office installed , 
i encounter a problem.i also carried dll files that has been added to project . what should i do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use the relevant object libraries you'll have to make sure that Office (Excel in your case) is installed on your client machine. If you have the option I'd suggest to switch to the Open Office XML format anyways. I recently had a similar problem with MS Word and the +work to switch to the new format has def. payed of.

Check [MS Open XML SDK](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&source=hp&q=office+open+xml+sdk&btnG=Google-Suche&meta=&aq=0&oq=office+open+xml+sd&fp=993ae16b619589dd)

Performace++ and not depending on Office installed...

Comment: could you please tell me how to use this sdk in my C# program ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612511/insert-openxmlelement-after-word-bookmark-in-open-xml-sdk is not 100% what you need, but it will point you in the right direction. HTH

Answer (score 4):

The Office COM objects depend on Office.  You should either arrange for Office to be installed on the other systems, or use a component for reading Excel files that doesn't need Excel installed, such as the ODBC Excel driver or a third-party Excel file reader.