# Insert in Word bookmarks - Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have to learn some things abount Open XML SDK, working with C#.
Things like @Ahmad Mageed answered here: [Insert OpenXmlElement after word bookmark in Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612511/insert-openxmlelement-after-word-bookmark-in-open-xml-sdk)

I'm in a similar situation, but in my case I need to insert text or elements inside the bookmark...(not after it)

Need some help please.
(Sorry for my English)
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. Check out the "Bookmarks" section on Eric White's article [Inserting / Deleting / Moving Paragraphs in Open XML Wordprocessing Documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/11/03/inserting-deleting-moving-paragraphs-in-open-xml-wordprocessing-documents.aspx).

Here's a way to insert between `bookmarkStart` and `bookmarkEnd`: [Replace bookmark text in Word file using Open XML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308299/replace-bookmark-text-in-word-file-using-open-xml-sdk)

Comment: But what i need is c# code using the "Open XML SDK"

The perfect example is the one I mention, but putting the elements after the bookmarks doesn't help for me.

ThankU @Otaku

Comment: @Dislaying: Got it. There's a link I've put above that should get you all the way there.